# Preserve Aspect, but with crop center

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, rawimage

I have a `GameObject` with `RawImage` component displaying an Image using `Texture`.

The image is squeezed to the size of the object and changing it's original ratio.

How can I tell the image in the texture to `CropCenter`? (like in Android for example)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I do with **landscape** images :

1. Create a parent `RawImage` element called "Mask" (works with `UI > Image` component too)
2. Add the `UI > Mask` component to it
3. Put your Smurf image (with the `RawImage component) as a child of the "Mask" object
4. Set the values of the child'`RectTransform` :

   - Anchors Min = (0.5, 0),
   - Anchors Max = (0.5, 1)
   - Top = 0
   - Bottom = 0
5. Add the `Layout > Aspect Ratio Fitter` to the Smurf image and set the `Aspect Mode` to "Height Controls Width" and the `Aspect Ratio` to the desired value (16/9 for example)

Check the image : Parent called "Mask" and your smurf image called "Image"

[image]

For **portrait** images, the `RectTransform` values :

- Anchors Min = (0, 0.5),
- Anchors Max = (1, 0.5)
- Left = 0
- Right = 0

The `Aspect Mode` of the child must be set to "Width Controls Heigh"

Comment: I found `AspectRatioFitter.AspectMode.EnvelopeParent` to be the most suitable for me, but your answer helped me a lot, Thanks bro!